# The link in <a> are not being styled as preferred, what's wrong in this html code?

Tags: html, css

The links in `<ul>` should be styled as ruled out in the `<style>`, but it is not working and the links are shown in the default way.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  background-color: pink;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin: 5px;
}

a:link a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: turquoise;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: cursive;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: green;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
}

a:active {
  background-color: green;
  border: 10px solid tomato;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>HTML OMG</header>
<ul>
  <li><a href="www.google.co.in" title="Link to Google" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.facebook.com" title="Link to Facebook" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.instagram.com" title="Link to Instagram" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.youtube.com" title="Link to Youtube" target="_blank">Youtube</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.twitter.com" title="Link to Twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

I checked the CSS is correct, but the output is something like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5MkY.png
I am new to HTML CSS so it is confusing me a lot.

Comment: @OP would you kindly read: [under what circumstances may I add urgent or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/5235984)

Comment: a:link, a:visited ? with comma

Comment: @takendarkk The links should be styled, i laid out the css rules but the links are styled as default only

Answer (score 0):

Your second style rule, `a:link a:visited` will only apply to an `<a>` tag that's within another `<a>` tag (specifically, a visited link that's within another link). I suspect you want this rule to apply to both `a:link` as well as `a:visited` - in which case you should separate the two with a comma - `a:link, a:visited` to get the rule content to apply to both selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a comma , i think that is your problem

```
 a, a:visited {......
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `a:link, a:visited` instead of `a:link a:visited` . The latter means a link **inside** of a visited link.

While the former means a link **and** a visited link.